# Merge Ruby Scripts

Tags: ruby

I am uploading content to a hosted CMS. They provide a Ruby Gem that allows me to upload lots of content programatically. I was able to upload my content by editing one of their scripts but I can't get the script to include my file with the upload. This is the script I am using successfully:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby -rubygems
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'authentication')
require "csv" # faster_csv (ruby 1.9)

lines = CSV.read(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'karaoke.csv')) # Exported an Excel file as CSV
lines.slice!(0) # remove header line
collection = StorageRoom::Collection.find('my collection ID')
Song = collection.entry_class
lines.each do |row|
 karaoke = Song.new(:artist => row[0], :song => row[1], :genre => row[2])
  if karaoke.save
    puts "Misuero Karaoke Latino saved: #{karaoke.artist}, #{karaoke.song}, #{karaoke.genre} "
  else
    puts "Misuero Karaoke Latino could not be saved: #{karaoke.errors.join(', ')}"
  end
end
```

This is the script, as per their example, that would do the file upload:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby -rubygems
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'authentication')

path = ::File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '..', 'spec', 'fixtures', 'image.png'))
collection = StorageRoom::Collection.find('my collection ID')

# Upload File
entry = collection.entry_class.new(:name => "StorageRoom Logo", :file => StorageRoom::File.new_with_filename(path))

if entry.save 
  puts "Entry saved (#{entry[:@url]})"
  puts "URL of the uploaded file is #{entry.image.url}"
  puts "URL of the automatically generated thumbnail is #{entry.image.url(:thumbnail)}" # Multiple Image Versions can be specified in the interface
else
  puts "Entry could not be saved: #{entry.errors.join(', ')}"
end
```

I want to mix both scripts so I only run one but I can't get the file upload portion to work at all. I am trying to upload a .mov. Where should the files be in relation to the script? How can I make it so they are named correctly? How would I edit the script so it does multiple files? And how can I merge the scripts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Where should the files be in relation to the script?

`File.dirname(__FILE__)` returns the directory of the current file and `File.join` allows you to add other directories to the path (`'..'` of course means parent directory) and `File.expand_path` ensures that this is an absolute rather than relative path.

> How can I make it so they are named correctly?

It's basically impossible to answer this without knowing your directory structure. To get a feel for it trying using the ruby console and experimenting with [the core file methods](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html).

> How would I edit the script so it does multiple files?

You'll probably want to loop the section beneath `# Upload File` over an array of filenames. You might find `Dir.entries`/ `Dir.glob` useful for generating this array: [Dir api docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Dir.html).

> And how can I merge the scripts?

Generally speaking: Concatenate files then remove the duplication (e.g. authentication, assigning the collection var). Your specific implementation will depend upon the structure of Song class (e.g. if this is object you're attaching files to you can probably just add `:file => StorageRoom::File.new_with_filename(path)` to the `new` statement in your first script) and/or csv (e.g. if this has the path of the file included you can just pass this without fiddling with `Dir.glob` etc.

Comment: Sweet. What does the spec fixtures part mean?

Comment: I tried this http://pastebin.com/Rb3Asm2v but I'm getting an error that says: import_csv.rb:22: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')' No idea what that means.

Comment: `your_rails_root/spec/fixtures/image.png` is an example image used for testing.

Looks like you've got a typo on line 15 that means your filename string isn't closed. Try `...StorageRoom::File.new_with_filename("#{karaoke.artist}#{karaoke.song}.mov"))`.

Comment: HOW FRUSTRATING!!! Lol sorry this is driving me nuts. I made those changes and that works but I guess i broke something else. This is what I have now http://pastebin.com/N08gqV5z but the error I am getting is   import_csv.rb:15:in `block in <main>': undefined method `artist' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
 from import_csv.rb:14:in `each'
 from import_csv.rb:14:in `<main>'

Comment: Ah, sorry should've spotted that sooner: You can't get the artist or song attributes until the karaoke object is created. In the middle of that assignment statement the `karaoke` variable is nil. Try `"#{row[0]}#{row[1]}.mov"`